# Get Google play store application url programmatically

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play-developer-api

I want to read url of the page when accessing Google play, whats the best way to do this on Android ?

To describe, user searches an app A, clicks on app A page, i want to read that url

Comment: and another one question, which starts with "I want to" ...while this is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can copy the URL from within the Google Play Store app by following these steps:

1. When viewing the app listing page, press the overflow menu (displayed as 3 dots in a column)
2. Press on the "Share" menu option
3. Press on "Copy to clipboard" option

You can then paste the URL on a text field to view it.

Comment: updated question, i want to do it programmatically, not manually

Comment: @user3826306 _Very possibly_ the best you could do might be to have a web-view embedded in your app, together with a "_This one_" button that the user presses when they've navigated to the app they want (I don't _actually_ know whether you can read the current URL of a web-view from the containing app: if you can't, this won't work).

Comment: @TripeHound  is there a way to do it with accessibility service, where i am able to read webview components including url

Comment: @user3826306 I've no idea if you _can_ do it (read the current URL of an embedded webiew component); I was just saying that's about the only way I can see of being able to do something like what you want. But I'm not and Android specialist, so (a) it might not be possible, and (b) there might be other ways of doing what you want that I don't know about.